# PHP values inside pdo->query or/and prepared statements

Tags: pdo

I'm limiting the amount of comments shown on the page by 2, $second_count counts how many posts are if more than 2 it limits and show's a Show All comments, that's what this is for.

If you look into the variable $limitPost, how do I add parameter inside it.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish but with PDO.

$limitPost = "DESC LIMIT **$second_count**,2"; *but this can lead to SQL INJECTIONS to my understanding.*

```
PUBLIC FUNCTION userComments($post_iD,$second_count)
{
    $limitPost = "DESC LIMIT 2";
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT C.com_id, C.uid_fk, C.comment, C.created, U.username, U.photo 
                                FROM comments C, users U 
                                WHERE U.status='1' AND C.uid_fk = U.uiD
                                AND C.msg_id_fk = :postiD 
                                ORDER BY C.com_id < :second_count");
    $sth->bindParam(':postiD', $post_iD, PDO::PARAM_INT);               
    $sth->bindParam(':second_count', $limitPost, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();

    $data = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $data;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is what $second_count is, it it's just counting if there are 2 comments showing, it'll hide all the rest and if I press show all comments it'll expand.

```
<?php
    $x=1;
    if($x){
        $comment_count  = count($commentsarray);
        $second_count   = $comment_count-2;

        if($comment_count>2){
?>
        <div class="comment_ui" id="view<?php echo $post_iD;?>">
            <a href="#" class="view_comments" id="<?php echo $post_iD;?>">Show all <?php echo $comment_count;?> comments</a>
        </div>
<?php
        $commentsarray  = $Wall->userComments($post_iD, $second_count);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Make it at least working without prepared statement

Comment: Thank you your common sense, for replying at least. The code is working correctly, there's nothing wrong with it..

Comment: if your parameter is an integer, you can just concat the parameter into the sql string with `..".intval($var)."..` intval is safe! (see here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) it always returns an integer

Comment: @x4rf41 this approach spoils the very idea of a prepared statement

Comment: Yes, @YourCommonSense, could you look at the update I made to the post and maybe let me know if It's really messed up?

Comment: @YourCommonSense: i know, but its the only solution to his problem as far as i know, pdo cant put parameters within parameters

Comment: @x4rf41 for a programmer it's quite easy, you know.

Comment: What does this second_count mean? Do you really want to select all the rows in case it is set to zero?

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's my fault I didn't explain, I posted too quickly without enough resources, I'll keep that in mind whenever I post again. Look at the update I made to the post, that should clear things up.

Answer (score -1):

alright:

> If you look into the variable $limitPost, how do I add another
>   variable inside it.
>
> This is what I'm trying to accomplish but with PDO.

impossible <- that is the answer to your question

Answer (score -1):

instead of :

```
:second_count
```

try:

```
DESC LIMIT 2
```

into the prepared statement. You really do not need the parameter :second_count in your prepared statement since it is a constant string.

SQL injections would be possible if :second_count was an input by a user, since is it constant, nothing like that is possible.

Why what you are doing is not working:

1. DESC LIMIT 2 is not an integer parameter, so the bind should fail or give out junk.
2. If you were to use PDO::PARAM_STR on the bind, :second_count would be put into qoutes, so the sql statement would fail.